# How to convert jsvalue to Map[string,Any] with spray-json?

Tags: scala, spray-json

In scala, I am giving input jsvalue as:

```json
[
  {"priority":1,"whoColumns":{"createdBy":"madhu","createdDate":1606111643373,"lastUpdatedBy":"manojkumar","lastUpdatedDate":1635923035513},"adType":1,"code":"pczpriy","id":3,"uploadDate":1606111560000,"payType":"P"},
  {"priority":1,"whoColumns":{"createdBy":"madhu","createdDate":1606111643373,"lastUpdatedBy":"manojkumar","lastUpdatedDate":1635923035513},"adType":1,"code":"pczpriy","id":3,"uploadDate":1606111560000,"payType":"P"}
]
```

I want to convert this into: `Map[String, Any]`
but I am getting following error in Postman:

> Expected Map as JsObject, but got [{"priority":1,"whoColumns":

And in eclipse I am getting error as Stacktrace:

> spray.json.package$.deserializationError(package.scala:23)

Comment: that's a sensible error message as you want to parse a List into a Map. In the example you give, there are 2 identical rows. How should these be represented in the resulting Map? Considering a Map is a Key/Value datastructure so you can't have both rows in it. In any case, if you want a `Map[K, V]` the input should be a Json object. If the input is a Json array, the parsed result will be `List`-like

Comment: Have `Any` is a symptom of something wrong